# Как в Qt 5.9 подключить драйвер MySql?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, linux-mint

Добрый день, пытаюсь подключиться к БД но в консоль выдаёт

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available
>   drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7

в настоечном файле всё прописано

> QT += core gui
>
> QT += network
>
> QT += sql

но ошибка не исчезает не знаю что делать.

Comment: Пользуясь Ubuntu и перейдя к версии 17.04, пересобрал `qmysql` согласно официальному [мануалу](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql-for-mysql-4-and-higher).

Comment: @alexis031182, а при чём здесь Ubuntu? Автор работает под Mint-ом (судя по меткам).

Comment: @alexis031182 не понял что такое файлы заголовков "MySQL header files" ?

Comment: @Arhad, Mint на убунте основан, если не ошибаюсь. Совместимость между ними имеется.

Comment: `такое файлы заголовков "MySQL header files"` — возможно те, которые содержатся в пакете *mysql-devel*.

Comment: @VargSieg, речь, видимо, о пакете с заголовочными файлами MySql, который потребуется установить перед сборкой драйвера.

Comment: [32 vs 64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31844328/4827341)?

Comment: @alexis031182 что то с инструкцией всё не совсем понятно там говориться You need the MySQL header files, as well as the shared library libmysqlclient.so и ещё your Linux distribution, you may need to install a package which is usually called "mysql-devel".  у меня Mint 18 где это всё можно взять ? Сам Qt установлен в пользовательской директории

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 64

Comment: @VargSieg, воспользуйтесь системным менеджером пакетов и поищите там пакет с названием, как и указал Arhad: "mysql-devel". Просто у разных дистрибутивов название может отличаться. Например, в убунте их сразу два (раздельно для клиента и сервера, я обычно ставлю оба): libmysqlclient-dev и libmysqld-dev

Comment: для mint-18 файл с библиотекой `libqsqlmysql.so` присутствует в пакете `libqt5sql5-mysql` (находится с помощью программы *apt-file*), заголовочные файлы находятся в пакете `libmysqld-dev` (находится с помощью программы *apt-cache*)

Comment: @VargSieg, *64* — это архитектура вашей программы? а архитектура библиотеки, которую программа пытается загрузить?

Comment: @alexis031182 может это и глупо, но можно по шагам с помощью synaptic я нашёл libmysqlclient-dev и libmysqld-dev оба отмечены в нём зелёным квадратиком, что нужно сделать дальше ?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin дык я не хочу ничего грузить просто подключиться к базе данных из своего проекта в Qt и до сих пор это никак не получается. Понять не могу что так сложно, вот в java  скачал JDBS Connector положил в папку с проектом, подключился в коде и всё работает как часы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin по вашему ответу выше libqt5sql5-mysql и libmysqld-dev они находятся в /usr/share/doc это правильно и что теперь сними делать ?

Comment: @VargSieg, это названия пакетов. что с ними делать? их надо установить. в них, к слову, входит множество файлов, распределённых по множеству каталогов. // но вообще я начинаю подозревать, что всё это вам мало поможет. вы же ведь установили (например, тот же qt) отнюдь не из **официальных** репозиториев (т.е., репозиториев дистрибутива), а из «левых» источников. и чтобы знающие люди (я к таковым не отношусь) сделали вам правильные подсказки, вам стоит прямо в вопросе описать, что и откуда вы брали и устанавливали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [официальной](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql-for-mysql-4-and-higher) инструкции, компиляция и установка драйвера `qsqlmysql` производится в три шага (при условии, что обозначенные там же в справке зависимости, как то пакет с заголовочными файлами MySql, уже установлены).

**Шаг первый.**

Открываем терминал и переходим в папку с проектом драйвера:

> cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql

Здесь "$QTDIR" - это путь к папке с установленным Qt.

**Шаг второй.**

> qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/lib
>   -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro

Здесь имеются нюанс: в системе может быть уже установлен Qt из пакетов. Удалять его вовсе не обязательно, но при сборке драйвера следует учитывать данную особенность. Поэтому прописываем полный путь именно к интересующей нас версии `qmake`. Например:

> ~/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include"
>   "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro

Далее правим путь в "LIBS" в соответствии с реальным местоположением `libmysqlclient_r.so`. Путь файла библиотеки можно посмотреть в том же Synaptic. В Ubuntu этот файл лежит в "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" (возможно, что это справедливо и для Mint). Итого, пример:

> ~/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include"
>   "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro

Секция "INCLUDEPATH" по умолчанию предлагает путь "/usr/local/include", хотя на самом деле в Ubuntu заголовочные файлы MySql лежат в "/usr/include/mysql". Если указать данный путь, то при компиляции будет выведена ошибка:

> fatal error: stdlib.h: Нет такого файла или каталога

Гугление по этой теме подсказало лишь одно верное решение: вообще не указывать "INCLUDEPATH". С чем связана подобная ошибка мне неизвестно, возможно кто-то сможет подсказать ответ.

Тем не менее, результирующая команда для сборки может выглядеть так:

> ~/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/bin/qmake "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro

**Шаг третий**

Собственно, сборка

> make

и установка драйвера

> make install

Comment: Адрес расположения драйверов у меня немного другой ~/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers $ из этой папки я набрал команду ~/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/bin/qmake "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro нажал ввод и получил Cannot find file: mysql.pro. Это о чём может говорить кроме того что его нет ? Файл libmysqlclient_r.so.18 я скачал и он установился в /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: @VargSieg, "~/Qt/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers" - неправильный путь. Это путь к уже собранным бинарникам sql-драйверов. Скомпилированные драйвера попадают на последнем шаге установки именно в эту папку. Вам же нужен иной путь. Например, у меня это: "~/Qt/5.9/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql". То есть рядом с папкой "gcc_64" в папке "5.9" у Вас должна быть папка "Src", где располагаются исходники Qt, необходимость установки которых Вы должны были отметить ещё на этапе установки фреймворка.

Comment: А там нет src а это можно как нибудь поправить ? не помню, что бы при установке qt у меня что то спрашивали

Comment: @VargSieg, обязательно спрашивают. Надо отметить галочкой установку исходников. По умолчанию она снята. Переустановите фреймворк через инсталлятор. Если ставили через online-версию, то там скорее всего будет доступно обновление и не потребуется переустанавливать всё полностью.

Comment: Всё заработало ) Прям как то внезапно единственное что делал до этого момента повторюсь скачал  и установил файл libmysqlclient_r.so.18 даже комп не перегружал просто случайно проект запустил и всё заработало )