# Ошибка при сборке драйвера MySql на Qt.

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, qt

Все делаю по этой [инструкции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676627/272778), но выходит ошибка qtsqldrivers-config.pri: No such file or directory[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Этого файла у меня вообще нет на компьютере.
Подскажите он что от меня требует

Answer (score 0):

Согласно официальной [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql-for-mysql-4-and-higher) надо делать так:

> You need the MySQL header files, as well as the shared library libmysqlclient.so. Depending on your Linux distribution, you may need to install a package which is usually called "mysql-devel".
>
> Tell qmake where to find the MySQL header files and shared libraries (here it is assumed that MySQL is installed in /usr/local) and run make:
>
> `cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers`
> `qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/local`
> `make sub-mysql`

**Перевод:** 
Как создать `QMYSQL` плагин на `Unix` и `MacOS`

Вам понадобятся заголовочные файлы `MySQL` и библиотека `libmysqlclient.so`. Кроме того, в зависимости от вашего дистрибутива `Linux`, вам возможно придется установить пакет который обычно называется "mysql-devel".

Укажите `qmake` где найти заголовочные файлы `MySQL` и общую библиотеку (здесь подразумевается, что `MySQL` установлен в `/usr/local`) и запустите `make`:

```
cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make sub-mysql
```